# Using a variable for if window.location.href.indexOf()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is use a variable with window.location.href.indexOf() This is my code right now, I want to be able to shorten it.

```
var urls  = [
'https://www.example.com/' 
,'https://www.example2.com/' 
,'https://www.example3.com/'  
,'https://www.example4.com/'
,'https://www.example5.com/'
];



// if ((window.location.href.indexOf(""+urls+"") > -1) Does not work
if (
(window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.example.com/") > -1)
|| (window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.example2.com/") > -1)
|| (window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.example3.com/") > -1)
|| (window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.example4.com/") > -1)
|| (window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.example5.com/") > -1)   
) {
//do stuff

}
```

I've included what I've tried in the code but it doesn not work. javascript and jquery both work for me

Comment: Use a for loop to iterate over your urls.

Comment: Are you trying to do a partial match here, or an exact match?

Comment: Would be exact match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check like this

```
if (urls.indexOf(window.location.href) > -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `indexOf` on array to search the `window.location.href` within array of urls.

*Change*

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf(""+urls+"") > -1)
```

*To*

```
if (urls.indexOf(window.location.href) > -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
if (urls.indexOf(window.location.href) > -1)
```

instead of

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf(""+urls+"") > -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var href = window.location.href; 

//there you need to strip params and leave only domain (https://www.example.com/index.php?q=a convert to https://www.example.com/)

//and then
if (urls.indexOf(href) > -1) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the URLs in an array, you can use a loop to test the URLs as follows:

```
var test = false;
for(var i=0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    test = test || location.href.indexOf(urls[i]) > -1;
}

if( test ) {
    //do stuff
}
```